# is there any possible chance when i input data into loop and doesnt entered into database?

Tags: php, loops

sorry for my bad english . i got problem with looping . my friend said when he used my program and he insert 20 data or more into database in one time , sometimes a data doesnt match with data previously entered .

an example : he insert 20 data and he just got 19 but the problem is that happening sometimes.

so im confused now , how can the program error just sometimes ?
here my code :

```
   else if ($mod == 'suratkeluar'){
    $batas = $_GET['batas'];
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {


     for ($i = 0; $i < $batas; $i++) {

        $idlot = $_POST['hiddenlot'][$i];
        $idbenang = $_POST['hiddenbenang'][$i];
        $benang = $_POST['jenisbenang'][$i];
        $warna = $_POST['warna'][$i];
        $lot = $_POST['lot'][$i];
        $harga = $_POST['hiddenprice'][$i];
        $netto = $_POST['netto'][$i];
        $box = $_POST['box'][$i];
        $cones = $_POST['cones'][$i];
        $ket = $_POST['keterangan'][$i];
        $cussplit = explode('_',$_POST['customer']);
        $idcus = $cussplit[0];
        $cus = $cussplit[1];
        $alamatcus = $cussplit[2];
        $kota = $cussplit[3];
        $POsplit = explode('_',$_POST['nopo']);
        $idpo=$POsplit[0];
        $nopo=$POsplit[1];
        $mobilsplit = explode('_',$_POST['kendaraan']);
        $kendaraan = $mobilsplit[0];
        $plat = $mobilsplit[1];
        $identitas = $_POST['identitas'][$i];
        $month = date('n');
        $years=date('Y');

    if($idlot != 0){
       $a=mysql_query("INSERT INTO surat_jalan VALUES ('',now(),'$_POST[nosurat]','$idlot','$benang','$warna','$lot','$harga','$netto','$box','$cones','$idcus','$cus','$alamatcus','$kota','$idpo','$nopo','$ket',1,'$month$years','$identitas','$kendaraan','$plat','$idbenang')");
           $aax=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM lot WHERE id_lot='$idlot'");
           $xx=mysql_fetch_array($aax);
            $net=$xx['netto'] - $netto; 
            $bbox=$xx['box'] - $box; 
            $ccones=$xx['cones'] - $cones;
            if($net == 0)
            {
            $a= mysql_query("UPDATE lot SET netto = '$net',
                                    box = '$bbox',
                                    cones = '$ccones',
                                    warning = 1
                                 WHERE id_lot = '$idlot'");
            } 
        else
        {
        $a=mysql_query("UPDATE lot SET netto = '$net',
                                        box = '$bbox',
                                        cones = '$ccones'
                                     WHERE id_lot = '$idlot'");
        }
        }
    $b = $i + 1;

        for ($c = 0; $c < $box; $c++) {
        $packinglist = $_POST["packinglist$b"][$c];
        $a= mysql_query("INSERT INTO packing_list VALUES('','$packinglist','$surat[id_surat]','$surat[no_surat_jalan]')");

        } 
}

}
}
```

Comment: WIll you please with some details ?

Comment: I think more details, yes. My first thought is that there's a problem with the data being input that's breaking the loop or possibly a timeout issue. I would get a concrete example of a failed instance. That is, get the 20 items your friend is trying to insert and have your code print you SQL and test each query directly in the database. That should give you more information

Comment: so i get report from my friend about my program. he said my program didnt work as ussualy , so i check in my copied program and work correctly. but he is keep tell me my program not working sometimes and not entered database but just 1 or 2 data from 20 data didnt entered the database. and make me more confused  is that happening sometimes. so what should i do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? I'll give an example but this could go with (probably) all queries. Let's say, this one (second from the last):

```
$a = mysql_query("UPDATE lot SET netto = '$net', box = '$bbox', cones = '$ccones' WHERE id_lot = '$idlot'");
```

To check if it was successful, you can add additional lines:

```
if ($a) // Success?
    print("Row has been updated.<br>");
else    // Error
    print("An error has occured; row has not been updated. Reason: ".mysql_error()."<br>");
```

If there are no redirections at the end, etc. and there is at least one error (the last one?), then your friend will see something like this:

> An error has occured; row has not been updated. Reason: #1054 - Unknown column 'cones' in 'where clause'
>
> An error has occured; row has not been updated. Reason: #1054 - Unknown column 'box' in 'field list'

With that help, you can see if there is an error in your queries or in application itself (timeout?).

There is also another problem: you're using PHP's mysql_API, which is deprecated. Instead, you should upgrade and use [mysqli_API](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: so if they input 20 rows of data the notice will appear 20 times ? but that nice idea . thanks buddy. is mysqli_API is same with my current ? im new at this lol

Comment: Yes, they will. But at least they will definitely see where the problem is. To see how are mysqli things going, you can visit here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp It hasn't got drastic changes but differ a little. If that helped, please mark as accepted to help future visitors with similar problem (and you will also get +2 rep). :)